# grep regex one-liner?

Tags: regex, grep

I have a large file that contains all surface forms of lexemes in a particular language.  I wanted to extract just the verb inflection patterns, specifically 1st, 2nd, 3rd person singular and plural in the present tense.

I tested the following regex using [this](https://regexr.com/4araj) online tool and it correctly identifies the lines I am trying to extract.

```
regex: Vm-p\d.+(e|p)
```

Below is a sample of what the file looks like with lines that are a *match*:

```
сломе                   сломити               Vm-p3p-an-n---e *match*
сломи                   сломити               Vmmp2s-an-n---e
сломи                   сломити               Vm-p3s-an-n---e *match*
сломивши                сломити               Rvp
сломиле                 сломити               Vmps-pfan-n---e
сломим                  сломити               Vm-p1s-an-n---e *match*
сломимо                 сломити               Vm-p1p-an-n---e *match*
сломите                 сломити               Vm-p2p-an-n---e *match*
сломићеш                сломити               Vmif2s-an-n---e
сломиш                  сломити               Vm-p2s-an-n---e *match*
иде                     ићи                   Vmia2s-an-n---p
иде                     ићи                   Vm-p3s-an-n---p *match*
идем                    ићи                   Vm-p1s-an-n---p *match*
идемо                   ићи                   Vm-p1p-an-n---p *match*
идео                    ићи                   Vmps-sman-n---p
идете                   ићи                   Vm-p2p-an-n---p *match*
идеш                    ићи                   Vm-p2s-an-n---p *match*
идоше                   ићи                   Vmia3p-an-n---p
иду                     ићи                   Vm-p3p-an-n---p *match*
идући                   ићи                   Rvp
иђасте                  ићи                   Vmii2p-an-n---p
иђаху                   ићи                   Vmii3p-an-n---p
иђаше                   ићи                   Vmii2s-an-n---p
ићи                     ићи                   Vmn----an-n---p
ишавши                  ићи                   Rvp
```

However, when I try to use grep on the command line, I can only get parts of it to work but not the whole thing together.  Is there a better way?  I wasn't able to find a good reference online.  I am expecting that I'll be searching for other patterns beyond this.

What have I tried? This works, but how can I combine them?

```
$ grep -P "Vm-p\d.+e" input.txt >> sr_verbs.txt
$ grep -P "Vm-p\d.+p" input.txt >> sr_verbs.txt
```

**Update:** As @kevinji pointed out, my original regex should have worked with the -P option.  I tried it again today and it did. Well, I guess I'm not sure exactly what I did.  Anyway, this works fine.

```
$ grep -P "Vm-p\d.+(e|p)" input.txt
```

Comment: Does `grep -P "Vm-p\d.+[ep]"` work?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @kevinji, yes it does!  You have the simplest answer.  Same output as anubhava. If you submit it as an answer, I mark it as the correct 'best' one.

Comment: Interesting, both [ep] and [e|p] work.

Comment: @SteveB Done, posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use what's called a regex "character class" by using brackets, which means "one of any of the characters contained here":

```
grep -P 'Vm-p\d.+[ep]'
```

Note that `[e|p]` is actually slightly different; it matches the characters `e`, `|`, or `p`.

I'm slightly surprised that `(e|p)` didn't work for you; in fact, `(?:e|p)` (a non-capturing group) should be identical to `[ep]`.

Comment: Actually, (e|p) does work now.  Hmm, that's interesting.  Maybe I polluted my regex with cyrillic p and e?  Oh well, thanks.

Comment: That would produce false matches within the target 3rd field and also against similar strings in other fields. See [@anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55315665/1745001) for a robust awk solution that will also work in any UNIX environment unlike this which is GNU grep only and relying on what the man page describes as "highly experimental" functionality!

Comment: @EdMorton I agree that `awk` is probably a better solution, but I don't see anywhere that states that `grep -P` is experimental. Perhaps you misread the `man` comment? "Interpret  `PATTERNS` as Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs).  This option is experimental when combined with the `-z` (`--null-data`) option, and  `grep -P` may warn of unimplemented features."

Comment: See https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep: `-P, --perl-regexp
    Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression. This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.`. Running `man grep` on my cygwin installation says the same thing.

Comment: @EdMorton Hmm, I'm running Grep 3.3 (the latest version) so it must have stabilized sometime in between your version of Grep and now. Good to know.

Comment: It still sounds kinda flaky to me even with the manual entry you posted so since no-one every NEEDS to use it I personally would avoid it but YMMV I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to handle with `awk`:

```
awk '$3 ~ /^Vm-p[0-9]+.+[ep]/' file
```

```
сломе                   сломити               Vm-p3p-an-n---e *match*
сломи                   сломити               Vm-p3s-an-n---e *match*
сломим                  сломити               Vm-p1s-an-n---e *match*
сломимо                 сломити               Vm-p1p-an-n---e *match*
сломите                 сломити               Vm-p2p-an-n---e *match*
сломиш                  сломити               Vm-p2s-an-n---e *match*
иде                     ићи                   Vm-p3s-an-n---p *match*
идем                    ићи                   Vm-p1s-an-n---p *match*
идемо                   ићи                   Vm-p1p-an-n---p *match*
идете                   ићи                   Vm-p2p-an-n---p *match*
идеш                    ићи                   Vm-p2s-an-n---p *match*
иду                     ићи                   Vm-p3p-an-n---p *match*
```

With `grep` you can use:

```
grep -E '[[:blank:]]Vm-p[0-9]+.+[ep]' file
```